# Is idolatry and adultery the same thing, spiritually?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis, avodah-zarah, arayot

Is idolatry and adultery the same thing, spiritually?

Can you say that if you do adultery you are worshiping the zodiac?
(maybe that was not your intention, but that's the reality?)

"They sacrifice on the tops of the mountains and burn offerings on the hills, under oak, poplar, and terebinth, because their shade is good. Therefore your daughters play the whore, and your brides commit adultery. I will not punish your daughters when they play the whore, nor your brides when they commit adultery; for the men themselves go aside with prostitutes and sacrifice with cult prostitutes, and a people without understanding shall come to ruin."HOSEA

Comment: Please [edit] this question to indicate why you suspect that there may be such an equivalence.

Comment: I have heard of idolatry being equated with adultery, but in my experience it's a one-way comparison. I've never heard of anyone saying "You did adultery, that's like you worshiped idols." (Although I don't tend to associate with people who commit adultery, I also don't tend to associate with people who commit idolatry)

Comment: @Daniel in certain respects, the term fetishism could apply to idolatry and adultery, but that's an English quirk. What even one way comparisons have you heard?

Comment: Please cite the exact chapter and verse and link to an online source (such as Chabad.org) In any case, this means that sexual immoraility is part of the worship of idols, not the "same thing spiritually". Also it is a reference to the waters of Sotah not working if the husband is also immoral.

Comment: @ShamanSTK See [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/adultery.html#3)

Comment: @Daniel I didn't know you were referring to the metaphorical language in tanakh of "whoring" after other deities or the metaphor of the unchaste wife. I guess I was confused by OP's question of equating the two spiritually.

Comment: @ShamanSTK Yes that's what I was trying to get to in my comment. If they were actually equivalent, you couldn't have a one-way relationship. If it's the same, it's the same. But you can have a metaphor only work one way. I didn't really express that clearly, though.

Comment: @Daniel You were as clear as you could have been. Really, it's the question that's the problem.

Comment: @ShamanSTK  Whats wrong whith the question?Sex outside marriage is not spiritual?

Comment: @Eagel because spiritual doesn't mean same thing. And no, the laws concerning relationships are not spiritual, whatever that means. The laws of monotheism belong to the category of law called misswoth, which are demanded by reason. Illicit relationships belong to chukim which reason neither demands nor denied, so they're rationally unrelated. You asked if they're spiritually the same thing. If yes, then idolatry is the same thing spiritually as eating a cheeseburger.

Comment: @ShamanSTK Sex is a common in idolatry,I have never heard that Cheesburger is a part of idoletry

Answer (score 3):

They're both very great sins. And in a poetic sense, the prophets compare the Jewish people worshipping idols to a woman straying from her husband. Similarly, "don't have idols" and "don't commit adultery" are the second commandments on each of the two tablets.

It's also worth noting that there was a sexual component to the worship of some Biblical idols.

But they are two different sins. Adultery is a sin, irrespective of worship issues.

Comment: I assume by "great sins" you mean "grevious/severe," not "fantastic" ...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I assume by "fantastic" you mean "good/superb," not "bizarre"...

Answer (score 0):

The gemara says, lo avdu yisrael avodah zarah ela le'hatir la'hem ha'arayos. The Jewish people only served idols in order to permit arayos for themselves.

This is pretty Freudian regardless of whether or not they are the same sin.

Ultimately the gemara seems to be indicating there is a yetzer hara to destroy the boundaries of the human personality, logic can be circumvented to access this goal via idolatry.